# Calculate percentage by groups

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, percentage

I need to calculate the percentage of the combination of one group, I have something like this

```
c1     c2    Month     Sol         Amnt

---     ---   ------   ------     -------
AA     BA   April       F           123
AA     BA   April       A           45
AA     BA   April       N           576
AB     AS   April       F           12
AB     AS   April       A           20
AA     BA   March       F           34
AA     BA   March       N           15
AA     BA   March       A           10
```

And I need the output to be something like this

```
c1      c2     Month   Sol        Amnt      Total      %

----  ----   -------    ----       ------     ------    -------
AA     BA     April      F          123        744       16.53%
AA     BA     April      A          45         744       6.05%
AA     BA     April      N          576        744       77.42%
AB     AS     April      F          12         32        37.50%
AB     AS     April      A          20         32        62.50%
AC     BA     March      F          34         59        57.63%
AC     BA     March      N          15         59        25.42%
AC     BA     March      A          10         59        16.95%
```

Comment: explain better your question

Comment: I have several combinations of values that repeat on C1 and C2, and I want to calculate their percentage based on the C1 & C2 combo depending on the month

Comment: You should edit your original question and post the SQL you have at the moment, and explain the question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to use Analytical Functions in order to compute it values by group.

```
select c1, c2, month, sol, Amnt
, sum(amnt) over(partition by c1,c2, month order by c1, c2) Total
, round((amnt / sum(amnt) over(partition by c1,c2, month order by c1,c2))*100,2)||'%' "%"
from TBL1;
```

The **magic** part is **over(partition...** applied to any aggregation.

> sum(amnt) over(partition by c1,c2, month order by c1, c2) Total

Results:
[image]

Comment: @Zombraz Nice to hear it worked as expected, and then this answer must be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TBL1
(
  c1 VARCHAR(20)
, c2 VARCHAR(20) 
, Month VARCHAR(20) 
, Sol VARCHAR(20) 
, Amnt integer 
);


   insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AA','BA','April','F',123);
   insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AA','BA','April','A',45);
   insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AA','BA','April','N',576);
   insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AB','AS','April','F',12);
   insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AB','AS','April','A',20);
   insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AC','BA','March','F',34);
   insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AC','BA','March','N',15);
   insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AC','BA','March','A',10);



SELECT
  Tbl1.*
  ,Grp.ttlAmt
  ,Tbl1.Amnt / Grp.ttlAmt * 100
FROM
  TBL1 
  left join ( 
  select c1 , sum(amnt) as ttlAmt from Tbl1 group by c1)Grp
  on Grp.c1 = Tbl1.C1
```

Added SQLfiddle link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ac79/2

Comment: TY Bob! But I'm gathering information from another set of subqueries, and it doesnt seem to work, heres my code.

Comment: post what you have so far

Comment: @Zombraz I added a SqlFiddle link for you

Comment: TY I'm creating all the tables that I'm using, let me finish some reports and will upload it as soon as I can, again TY for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle, I added the following inserts to try to make a better example of me information.

Comment: insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AA','BA','March','N',65);
   insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AA','BA','March','A',35);

Comment: insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AB','AS','March','A',40);
   insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AB','AS','March','N',35);
   insert INTO tbl1 (c1,c2,Month,Sol,Amnt) values ('AB','AS','March','F',25);

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your query:

```
TO_CHAR((amnt/total)*100||'%' as "%"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same table grouped  by different leve  of aggregation

```
select c1, c2, Month, Sol, Tot_Sol_Amnt, Tot_Amnt, (Tot_Sol_Amnt/Tot_Amnt )*100 as perc 
from (
 select t2.c1 as c1, t2.c2 as c2, t2.Month as Month, t2.Sol as Sol, sum(t2.Amnt) as Tot_Sol_Amnt
      from tbl1 t2
      group by  t2.c1, t2.c2, t2.Month, t2.Sol
) tt1 inner join (
 select t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.Month, sum(t1.Amnt) Tot_Amnt
        from tbl1 t1
        group by  t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.Month
) tt2  on tt1.c1  = tt2.c1 AND tt1.c2  = tt2.c2 AND tt1.month  = tt2.month
```